# Add a background map for sigma js

Tags: background, leaflet, sigma.js

I have created a graph in Gephi using GeoLayout (showing network over the world). Now for my visualization I would like to add a background map in sigma.js ideally something like openstreetmap or a similar service. Is that possible? 
Otherwise I could also imagining adding the graph to a leaflet map if that is easier. In any case I would need to know how this can be achieved. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hey @oddpodm, how did you solve this? I have the same requirement, and am looking aroudn at the various visualisation tools. Cheers - Brock